# Converting a PIL image in python to grayscale pixel by pixel, leaving 1 color alone

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, image-manipulation

I'm trying to convert an image to grayscale in python 3.4.2, but I would like to leave all "red" pixels alone

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageOps


def grayscale(picture):
    res = Image.new(picture.mode, picture.size)
    red = '150,45,45'                    # for now I'm just tyring
    x = red.split(",")                   # to change pixels with R value less than 150 
                                         #and G/B values greater than 45
    width, height = picture.size         #to greyscale 

   for i in range(0, width):
       for j in range(0, height):
           pixel = picture.getpixel((i, j))  #get a pixel
           pixelStr = str(pixel)
           pixelStr = pixelStr.replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
           pixelStr.split(",")                 #remove parentheses and split so we 
                                               #can convert the pixel into 3 integers


           #if its not specifically in the range of values we're trying to convert
           #we place the original pixel otherwise we convert the pixel to grayscale

           if not (int(pixelStr[0]) >= int(x[0]) and int(pixelStr[1]) <= int(x[1]) and int(pixelStr[2]) <= int(x[2])):
              avg = (pixel[0] + pixel[1] + pixel[2]) / 3
              res.putpixel((i, j), (int(avg), int(avg), int(avg)))
           else:
              res.putpixel(pixel)
return res
```

Right now this converts the image to grayscale but as far as I can tell it doesn't leave any colored pixels like I thought it would, any help/suggestions/alternate ways to accomplish my task would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I tried to follow these directions:
     1 Read image from file
     2 Loop through and call getpixel() on each pixel to get its colour
     3 Compare its r/g/b to your desired colour. If it falls outside some 
     threshold of your desired colour, use some formula to convert to 
     greyscale (e.g. set rgb to the average of the 3 values) and use 
     putpixel to replace that pixel
Save image
There are probably much more efficient ways, but this is a simple way to get what you want.

Comment: If you want to leave the **red** pixels alone, you could have obtained the **red channel** of your image and performed threshold on that. Then you could masked the resulting image with your original to get all red and close to red pixels. I wouldn't have to write this big a code

Answer (score 0):

So incase anyone reads this in the future my code was not working due to an error on my part

```
res.putpixel(pixel)
```

should have been throwing an error, because I didn't get it a position to place the pixel just the color information. Since it wasn't throwing an error we never actually got inside my else: statement.

Asked a teammate for help and we changed my code to this:

```
from numpy import *
from PIL import Image

red_lower_threshold = 150
green_blue_diff_threshold = 50
def grayscale(picture):
   res = Image.new(picture.mode, picture.size)

   for i in range(0, picture.size[0]):
       for j in range(0, picture.size[1]):
           pixel = picture.getpixel((i, j))  #get a pixel
           red = pixel[0]
           green = pixel[1]
           blue = pixel[2]

           if (red > red_lower_threshold and abs(green - blue) < green_blue_diff_threshold):
               res.putpixel((i, j), pixel)
           else:
               avg = (pixel[0] + pixel[1] + pixel[2]) / 3
               res.putpixel((i, j), (int(avg), int(avg), int(avg)))

res.save('output.jpg')
return res
```

it's not perfect but its a workable solution